# Correct way to use Mockito for JdbcOperation

Tags: junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito and trying to cover following source code:

```
jdbcOperations.update(insertRoleQuery,new Object[]{"menuName","subMenuName","subSubMenuName","aa","bb","cc","role"});
```

In this query is taking 7 string parameters. I have written the mockito test case for the code and it's also covering the source code but I am not sure whether it's the correct way or not.

```
when(jdbcOperations.update(Mockito.anyString(), new Object[]{Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString()})).thenThrow(runtimeException);
```

Please suggest if i am doing it right way or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3), you can either use exact values, or argument matchers, but not both at the same time:

> **Warning on argument matchers:**
>
> If you are using argument matchers, all arguments have to be provided
>   by matchers.

If you do mix them, like in your sample, mockito will complain with something similar to

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at MyTest.shouldMatchArray(MyTest.java:38)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

In your case you don't seem to care about the array contents, so you can just use `any()`:

```java
when(jdbcOperation.update(anyString(), any())).thenThrow(runtimeException);
```

---

If you want to at least check the number of parameters, you can use either

- [org.mockito.Mockito's `argThat(argumentMatcher)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#argThat(org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher)):

```java
when(jdbcOperation.update(anyString(), argThat(array -> array.length == 7))).thenThrow(runtimeException);
```

- [org.mockito.hamcrest.MockitoHamcrest's `argThat(hamcrestMatcher)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html#argThat(org.hamcrest.Matcher)):

```java
when(jdbcOperation.update(anyString(), argThat(arrayWithSize(7)))).thenThrow(runtimeException);
```

---

If you're interested in matching certain values, you can use [`AdditionalMatchers.aryEq(expectedArray)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html#aryEq(T[])), or just `Mockito.eq(expectedArray)` which has a special implementation for arrays, but I fell that the first one expresses your intent in a clearer way.

```
when(jdbcOperation.update(anyString(), aryEq(new Object[]{"whatever"}))).thenThrow(runtimeException);
```